# Magento: How to Display Product Images by Image Role

Tags: magento2

I am trying to figure out how to display product images by their image role inside `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml`

Each product on my shop page will have three images each with their own image role (base, preview, hover).

This is how my product currently looks:

[image]

Here is my image_with_borders.phtml file:

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image */ ?>

<img
    src="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getImageUrl()) ?>"
    alt="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getLabel(), null, true) ?>"
    class="main"
    max-width="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getWidth()) ?>"
    max-height="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getHeight()) ?>"
/>

<img src="" alt="" class="preview">

<img src="" alt="" class="hover">
```

How can I request the images with the roles, base, preview and hover in this file?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already identified a file to modify you can use js or knockout js to alter the image according to its role.
For example image with the hover role, you can use js with hover event, when the user mouse over you can process to change the image.